# Explicitly constructor and virtual function call during the object lifetime

Tags: c++, constructor

We can call a constructor using qualified-name, although the constructor doesn't have a name. Indeed 3.4.3.2/2:

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the
>   nested-name-specifier nominates a class C:
>
> — if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the
>   injected-class-name of C (Clause 9), or
>
> [...]
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }

    A(){ }
};

struct B : A
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }

    B()
    {
        foo();
    }  
};

struct C : B
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }

    C() : B(){ }      
};

C c;

int main()
{
    c.foo();
    C::C(); // Prints B
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfdfed40a5cc00be)

The line `C::C()` prints B. But it's unclear. Section 12.7/4 says:

> When a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a
>   constructor or from a destructor, including during the construction or
>   destruction of the class’s non-static data members, and the **object** **to**
>   **which the call applies** is the object (call it x) **under construction or**
>   **destruction**, the function called is the final overrider in the
>   constructor’s or destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a
>   more-derived class

In an explicit constructor call `c` has already fully-contructed. So the rule I cited cannot be used to explain such behavior. Is it UB at all? Could you explain it?

Comment: What does `C::C();` has to do with the object `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can call a constructor using qualified-name, although the constructor doesn't have a name.

Your premise is completely wrong. In the *very same* paragraph you cited (§3.4.3.1 [class.qual]/p2):

> Such a constructor name shall be used only in the *declarator-id* of a
>   declaration that names a constructor or in a *using-declaration*.

Is `C::C();` a declaration that names a constructor? No. Is it a *using-declaration*? Obviously not.

It's ill-formed. Clang seems to consider it to name the type instead, for some reason - probably a bug (its handling of *injected-class-names* is also buggy in other respects).

---

I also have no idea how you came to the conclusion that the behavior of `C::C();` - which, incidentally, only makes any sense if you consider `C::C` to name the type - could possibly be affected by the state of `c`, which appears nowhere in the expression nor in any of the relevant functions.

A hypothetical explicit constructor call on an object would have to look like `c.C::C();`, because the constructor is a *non-static* member function. And it makes no sense whatsoever to permit you to call a constructor on an already-constructed object - what does that even mean?

Comment: My first thought was that `C::C` should name a type, since `C` is the *injected-class-name*, however as you say the very text that was quoted  says that it is instead considered to name the constructor in this context

Comment: It was my inattention. `C::C()` obviously has no any sense. But clang didn't throw a compile-time error and I assume that it is correct.  I've understood that there is no way to explicitly constructor call. Thank you.

Comment: @MattMcNabb But as T.C. noted the constructor is non-static member function. Since, the program must be ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

The line...

```
C::C();
```

is outputting...

```
B
```

because `foo()` is being called from within `B`'s constructor so it'll use `B`'s version of `foo()`.

Any time `C`'s constructor is called, 
`C::C()` calls `A`'s constructor which calls `B`'s constructor in which `foo()` is called so `B`'s version of `foo()` is used, and then `C`'s constructor body (which you left empty) is finally called.

---

Let's ignore the fact that calling `C::C()` from `main()` like that doesn't conform to C++ standards.  You seem to be misinterpreting part of Section 12.7/4:

> ...the function called is the final overrider in the constructor’s or
>   destructor’s class and not one overriding it in a more-derived class

The call to foo is in `B` so the

> ...constructor's class...

is `B` and therefore

> ...not one overriding it in a more-derived class.

(which would be `C`).

You also mention "In an explicit constructor call `C` has already fully-contructed." The line...

```
C c;
```

will not change the behavior mentioned in Section 12.7/4.  `foo()` is still called `B`'s constructor and therefore

> ...the function called is the final overrider in the construtor's or destructor's class.