# calling constructor from member function

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Here's the question:

Define a class called Month that is an abstract data type for a month. Your class will have one member variable of type int to represent a month (1 for January, 2 for February, and so forth). Include all the following member functions: a constructor to set the month using the first three letters in the name of the month as three arguments, a constructor to set the month using an integer as an argument (1 for January, 2 for February, and so forth), a default constructor, an input function that reads the month as an integer, an input function that reads the month as the first three letters in the name of the month, an output function that outputs the month as an integer, an output function that outputs the month as the first three letters in the name of the month, and a member function that returns the next month as a value of type Month . Embed your class definition in a test program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Month
{
public:
    Month (char letter1, char letter2, char letter3);
    Month (int numOfMonth);
    Month ();
    void inputAsNum(); // read month as integer
    void inputAsCh(); //  read first three chars of month
    void outputAsCh() const;
    void outputAsNum() const;
    Month nextMonth();
private:
    int month;
};

int main()
{
    Month test(5);
    //test.inputAsNum();
    cout << "Current month is " << endl;
    test.outputAsCh();
    test.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;
    test.nextMonth();
    cout << "Next month is " <<endl;
    test.outputAsCh();
    test.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;

    Month test2('a','p','r');
    //test2.inputAsCh();
    cout << "Current month is " << endl;
    test2.outputAsCh();
    test2.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;
    test2.nextMonth();
    cout << "Next month is " <<endl;
    test2.outputAsCh();
    test2.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;


    Month test3;
    test3.inputAsNum();
    cout << "Current month is " << endl;
    test3.outputAsCh();
    test3.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;
    test3.nextMonth();
    cout << "Next month is " <<endl;
    test3.outputAsCh();
    test3.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;

    Month test4;
    test4.inputAsCh();
    cout << "Current month is " << endl;
    test4.outputAsCh();
    test4.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;
    test4.nextMonth();
    cout << "Next month is " <<endl;
    test4.outputAsCh();
    test4.outputAsNum();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

Month::Month (char letter1, char letter2, char letter3)
{
    if ((letter1 == 'j')&&(letter2 == 'a')&&(letter3 == 'n'))
        month= 1;
    else if ((letter1 == 'f')&&(letter2 == 'e')&&(letter3 == 'b'))
        month= 2;
    else if ((letter1 == 'm')&&(letter2 == 'a')&&(letter3 == 'r'))
        month= 3;
    else if ((letter1 = 'a')&&(letter2 == 'p')&&(letter3 == 'r'))
        month= 4;
    else if ((letter1 == 'm')&&(letter2 == 'a')&&(letter3 == 'y'))
        month= 5;
    else if ((letter1 == 'j')&&(letter2 == 'u')&&(letter3 == 'n'))
        month= 6;
    else if ((letter1 == 'j')&&(letter2 == 'u')&&(letter3 == 'l'))
        month= 7;
    else if ((letter1 == 'a')&&(letter2 == 'u')&&(letter3 == 'g'))
        month= 8;
    else if ((letter1 == 's')&&(letter2 == 'e')&&(letter3 == 'p'))
        month= 9;
    else if ((letter1 == 'o')&&(letter2 == 'c')&&(letter3 == 't'))
        month= 10;
    else if ((letter1 == 'n')&&(letter2 == 'o')&&(letter3 == 'v'))
        month= 11;
    else if ((letter1 == 'd')&&(letter2 == 'e')&&(letter3 == 'c'))
        month= 12;
}
Month::Month (int numOfMonth)
                    :month(numOfMonth)
{ }
Month::Month ()
                    :month(1)
{ }
void Month::inputAsNum()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter num of month => ";
    cin  >> num;
    month = num;
}
void Month::inputAsCh()
{
    char c1,c2,c3;
    cout << "Enter three letters of month => ";
    cin  >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
    Month::Month(c1,c2,c3);
}
void Month::outputAsCh() const
{
    if (month == 1)
        cout << "Jan ";
    else if (month == 2)
        cout << "Feb ";
    else if (month == 3)
        cout << "Mar ";
    else if (month == 4)
        cout << "Apr ";
    else if (month == 5)
        cout << "May ";
    else if (month == 6)
        cout << "Jun ";
    else if (month == 7)
        cout << "Jul ";
    else if (month == 8)
        cout << "Aug ";
    else if (month == 9)
        cout << "Sep ";
    else if (month == 10)
        cout << "Oct ";
    else if (month == 11)
        cout << "Nov ";
    else if (month == 12)
        cout << "Dec ";
}
void Month::outputAsNum() const
{
    cout << month;
}
Month Month::nextMonth()
{
    if (month < 12)
        month++;
    else if (month == 12)
        month = 1;
    return Month(month);
}
```

The code runs just fine. I try that calling constructor `Month::Month (char letter1, char letter2, char letter3)` from member function `void Month::inputAsCh()` . I can solve the problem by changing definition of `Month::inputAsCh()` and copy paste definitions of the constructor into the function. But, just out of curiosity, can be a constructor called from member function ? If it's okey, `Month::inputAsCh()` works wrong, I also try on `Month test4` variable.

```
Output                                  Expected Output
-------------                           -----------------
Current month is                        Current month is 
Nov 11                                  Nov 11
Next month is                           Next month is 
Dec 12                                  Dec 12
Current month is                        Current month is 
Apr 4                                   Apr 4
Next month is                           Next month is 
May 5                                   May 5
Enter num of month => 2                 Enter num of month => 2
Current month is                        Current month is 
Feb 2                                   Feb 2
Next month is                           Next month is 
Mar 3                                   Mar 3
Enter three letters of month => apr     Enter three letters of month => apr
Current month is                        Current month is 
Jan 1                                   Apr 4
Next month is                           Next month is 
Feb 2                                   May 5
```

Comment: No not like you're doing. The actual instance won't be affected by a constructor call.

Comment: It's called "constructor" for a reason : you can only construct an object once. After that, the object is alive until its destruction. If you can call an object's methods, then it is already alive, so an object trying to reconstruct itself inside its method would not make sense.

Comment: The `Month::Month(c1,c2,c3);` in `outputAsCh()` is practically a NOOP. You are calling a constructor but the constructed object isnt assigned to anything, it is local to the method and thus any reasonable compiler will completely optimize it away. The other occurence (`return Month(month);`) is fine. Creating another month does not affect the month on which the method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Month::Month(c1,c2,c3);
```

That line doesn't update the current object. It should be an error because `Month::Month` names the constructor in that context, but some compilers (notably `clang`) will interpret it as the construction of a temporary object instead (thanks to user657267 for the correction).

You could factor out your month calculation code into a separate function, then call that from both your constructor and your `inputAsCh` function:

```
void setMonth(char letter1, char letter2, char letter3)
{
    if ((letter1 == 'j')&&(letter2 == 'a')&&(letter3 == 'n'))
        month= 1;
    else if ((letter1 == 'f')&&(letter2 == 'e')&&(letter3 == 'b'))
        month= 2;
    else if ((letter1 == 'm')&&(letter2 == 'a')&&(letter3 == 'r'))
        month= 3;
    else if ((letter1 = 'a')&&(letter2 == 'p')&&(letter3 == 'r'))
        month= 4;
    else if ((letter1 == 'm')&&(letter2 == 'a')&&(letter3 == 'y'))
        month= 5;
    else if ((letter1 == 'j')&&(letter2 == 'u')&&(letter3 == 'n'))
        month= 6;
    else if ((letter1 == 'j')&&(letter2 == 'u')&&(letter3 == 'l'))
        month= 7;
    else if ((letter1 == 'a')&&(letter2 == 'u')&&(letter3 == 'g'))
        month= 8;
    else if ((letter1 == 's')&&(letter2 == 'e')&&(letter3 == 'p'))
        month= 9;
    else if ((letter1 == 'o')&&(letter2 == 'c')&&(letter3 == 't'))
        month= 10;
    else if ((letter1 == 'n')&&(letter2 == 'o')&&(letter3 == 'v'))
        month= 11;
    else if ((letter1 == 'd')&&(letter2 == 'e')&&(letter3 == 'c'))
        month= 12;
}

Month::Month (char letter1, char letter2, char letter3)
{
    setMonth(letter1, letter2, letter3);
}

void Month::inputAsCh()
{
    char c1,c2,c3;
    cout << "Enter three letters of month => ";
    cin  >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
    setMonth(c1,c2,c3);
}
```

Incidentally, your `setMonth` function could be greatly simplified by creating a `std::string` from those `char`s and comparing with that instead.

Comment: `Month::Month(c1,c2,c3);` tries to call the constructor, it simply isn't valid. `Month(c1,c2,c3);` would construct a temporary.

Comment: I'm aware of usage string. If a constructor is called by member function, it is temporary and makes no sense ? Isn't there any way to use unlike temporary ? Should be one more function defined to do it ?

Comment: @user657267 I remember reading something about arbitrary nesting of class names, but I can't remember what the rule is. Interestingly, `gcc` displays an error for things like `Month::Month::Month`, but `clang` doesn't even issue a warning. Do you have any standards quotes for this?

Comment: @user657267 [class]/2 in N3337: `A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the class-name is seen. The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself.` This makes me think that `Month::Month` is a valid type to use for a function-style explicit type conversion.

Comment: I'm aware of usage string. If a constructor is called by member function, it is temporary and makes no sense ? Isn't there any way to use unlike temporary ? Should be one more function defined to do it ?  @TartanLlama

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname calling the constructor of an already existing object doesn't make sense, you need to provide a separate function.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname in C++ `Type(value)` means to create object of type `Type` with initializer `value`

Comment: If I replace `Month::Month(c1,c2,c3);` with `*this = Month(c1,c2,c3);` what does it exactly do ? @TartanLlama @Matt McNabb

Comment: That constructs a new month object and then assigns it to the current object.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname That invokes `operator=` on `*this` with the temporary object as argument

Comment: @TartanLlama It took me a while and now my brain hurts, but I *think* that according to [class.qual]/2 `Month::Month` will refer to the constructor and not the type: `In a lookup in which function names are not ignored33 and the nested-name-specifier nominates a class C: [...] if the name specified after the nested-name-specifier, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name of C [...] the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C.`

Comment: @user657267 Nice, I think you're right. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: @user657267 - Your interpretation is incorrect. Since you are referring to the standard, read the very first sentence of 12.1, [class.ctor]: **Constructors do not have names.** You cannot refer to the constructor.

Comment: @DavidHammen [class.qual]/2 "Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration."

Comment: @TartanLlama - That to me is a bug in the standard, not in gcc and clang. How can you refer to something by name that the standard elsewhere says has no name?

Comment: @DavidHammen I agree, but I'd say that the exception takes precedence for interpretation, no?

Comment: @TartanLlama - Regardless of the language lawyer interpretation of [class.qual]/2, you can't call the constructor directly. (Constructors have no name.) You can call a constructor indirectly by creating an object of that type, but the call is always indirect, and it's always in the context of creating or re-creating (e.g., placement new) an object.

Comment: @DavidHammen Absolutely, I don't think I implied to the contrary.

Comment: @TartanLlama - The exception is that a complicated constructor is typically defined outside of the body of the class definition. There has to be a way to "name" the constructor to enable defining the constructor outside the class. In the example code of [class.qual]/2, that outside-of-class definition is just  `A::A() {}`. The non-binding example code in [class/qual]/2 suggests  `A::A a;` should be illegal. (The binding wording suggests otherwise.) Neither gcc nor clang balk at the example code in [class.qual]/2.

Comment: @DavidHammen It's also a [bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13403) in clang, with two duplicates. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558507/injected-class-names-of-class-templates) another example (albeit with templates), and here's [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25541197/657267). Regardless of the potentially confusing wording in the standard, the consensus is that `Foo::Foo` as used in this context is an error.

Comment: @user657267 - I wouldn't necessarily call this a bug in clang (or in gcc, which exhibits the same behavior). The section to which you reform [class.qual]/2, starts with "*In a lookup in which the constructor is an acceptable lookup result* ..." The constructor is not "an acceptable lookup result" in the context of `Month::Month(c1,c2,c3);`. Constructors normally have no name. The only contexts that I can see where this does apply are the non-inline definition of a constructor and various `using` constructs. The standard's example code hints at something else, but example code is not binding.

Comment: @DavidHammen `The standard's example code hints at something else, but example code is not binding` As mentioned earlier, immediately above that example is `Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration.`. Since OP's example is in a context where function names are not ignored, the injected class name refers to the constructor, which cannot be used here, hence the error. The example that follows might not be binding but I think the intent is clear.

Comment: @DavidHammen Also clang and gcc **do** give errors for the example code, but only gcc picks up the error in `struct Foo { void bar() { Foo::Foo(); } };`. Try it on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ if you're using an older version.